# User input validation of Maxima commands using PHP and/or Maxima

Tags: php, security, tomcat, maxima

I have **maxima** running on a **tomcat** server, that I access using **php**.

On my website, users are capable of executing maxima commands, that are sent to my tomcat server using php.

However, this leaves me with the problem of making sure that the user-supplied input is secure. For example I want to forbid the use of dangerous maxima functions like `writefile` (among many others).

Currently I am simply validating the input using php, using a list of blacklisted words, whose occurence I check using `strpos`. Obviously this isn't secure at all, because the user could simply enter `'write' . 'file' . '()'` instead of `writefile()`, thus circumventing the check for blacklisted words.

I am doubting that PHP is what I should use to make sure that the provided input is secure, so I am wondering if there is a way to blacklist certain functions INSIDE maxima on my tomcat server?

Comment: upvoting, because it's an interesting, think-out-of-the-box question for an average php-dev

Answer (score 2):

IMO, Multi-tier security solution is your only choice.

1. Validate php user input as much as you can. Don't forget to limit maximum allowed input length
2. Maxima is open-source, so you can rip off all 'dangerous' commands.  I have a limited lisp knowledge so I can't say if users will be able to hack around this limitation.
3. Put your tomcat  in jail/virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree w/ strangeqargo about multi-tier security and have just a few ideas to contribute.

These outside-of-Maxima steps are probably most important:

- jail/VM
- limit size of input and output
- limit memory and/or cpu time spent on any one computation

These inside-of-Maxima steps are less important once the preceding stuff is covered:

- disallow `:lisp` input
- disallow Lisp symbols (i.e. `?foo`)
- redefine functions which ordinarily have side effects (e.g. functions to read and write files) to do nothing

I think if you redefine side-effect functions, you don't need to bother with a blacklist. Users can call `writefile` or whatever but it has no effect. You can redefine a built-in function in Maxima and your new definition takes precedence over the built-in version. Note that the notation `foo([a]) := ...` means that `a` is a list of all the arguments (any number of arguments), so you don't need to think about how many arguments each function takes.

```
writefile ([a]) := false;
```

For good measure, you can remove the built-in Lisp function too.

```
?fmakunbound (writefile);
```

See [FMAKUNBOUND](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fmakun.htm) in the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/index.htm).

Comment: I think he should use blacklist just for logging malicious users.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Another way to go about it is to redefine blacklisted functions so that all they do is write a message to a log file. Something like: `writefile([a]) := block(printf(my_log, "Hey, writefile was called.~%"), false);`